# \cdot not displaying properly

Tags: math-mode, equations, packages

So I am trying to write the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \Delta C = \nabla C\cdot \Delta (w_i, b_l)
\end{equation}
```

The issue here is that the \cdot command which should show a dot indicating the dot product or multiplication instead is displaying a hyphen "-". I have tried writing the same equation as:

```
\begin{math}
    \Delta C = \nabla C\cdot \Delta (w_i, b_l)
\end{math}
```

This still displayed the same thing. I tried using centerdot but that didn't work either. I tried using both inline and display modes for \cdot but again get a hyphen output instead of a dot. I believe it might be something with my packages but I have haven't had any luck finding the correct one.

These are the following packages I am using:

```
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

I am fairly new to LaTeX and would appreciate any support on the matter, thank you!

Comment: Can you include an image of the output? Do you receive any warnings in your `.log`?

Comment: please post a test document not fragments, but fdsymbol is the usual issue

Comment: So I commented out fdsymbol and it worked. I was only using it to display \smallblackstar in an equation I was using to keep with notation. But I swapped it out with \circledast. Thanks a lot for the help was crazy fast!